# How to modify a .txt file on Windows server via web GUI

Tags: windows, user-interface, web

I need to be able to read, display, modify and save the contents of an existing .txt file which is located on a Windows server. I can do the 'read' and 'display' bits already, but not the modify and save back the file.

For example :

Text file is located here : www.myserver.com/files/textfile.txt
Content of file is : one_whole_line_like_this

I could of course do it via an FTP client, but I need something more elegant and easier for the end user, so I want the user to be able to access a (password protected) webpage and have it display the current content of textfile.txt (I can do up to here), then have a text box to enter the new content and a 'submit' button. The submit button then writes the new content of the text box to the file, keeping its original name (textfile.txt).

At the moment I'm stuck with thinking which is the best way to do it, never mind implementing it.

I would really appreciate suggestions on the easiest and most elegant way (for the user) to do this. Some example code would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming in this answer that you have a function web server. Otherwise, I suggest installing [Apache](http://www.apache.org/). There's plenty of [instructions](http://techblog.ankitaoza.com/2011/08/08/install-apache-php-on-window-server-2008-r2/) on the web if you need help setting it up. Natively, Apache can create password protected web pages. But, you'll need an SSL extension to actual encrypt information. You will also need [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php), which you will use to save new files on the server. You can get all this as an all-in-one package, like [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), as well.

If or when you have a functioning web server, you'd be using a mixture of [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/), [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) for an actual web page.

The general id is you have a client using the webpage. On the client's webpage, you will have a script that sends the data back to your server. On the server, you'll have another script that receives the data and then stores it into the file you want.

First, you'll want to design the page that the client will be visiting. You do that with [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). You'd use [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/) to add a text box and other things and [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) to change the way it looks on the page.

An HTML example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <textArea>My first html page!</textArea>
    <button>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

A CSS example:

```
body { background-color: black; }
textArea { width:50%; }
```

Then you'd collect the information in the text box with [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) on the browser. Then, you'd send that request to a [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) script on the server. In the [PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) script you save the data to the file request. Here's a rough example that uses [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [Jquery - Javascript extension](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/):

```
<script>

/*
    The $( "#submitButton" ) is executed every time the user clicks the div that is
    associated with it.

    The text in the textbox is returned from $( "#submitBox" ).text( );

    in $.post, here's what's happening

    $.post( ( script name ), ( data to be sent to script ) )

    So when your executing $.post( "php_file.php", new_text:$("#submitBox").text() )

    You're starting a script called php_file.php and sending the text in text box to a 
    variable called new_text.
*/
$( "#submitButton ).click( function( ){

    $.post( "php_file.php", new_text : $( "#submitBox" ).text( ) );

});

</script>
```

PHP Script

```
<?php
file_put_contents( "filename.txt", $_POST[ "new_text" ] );
?>
```

As these are just snippets of code, I would suggest reading up on HTML, CSS, Javascript, and PHP. You'll find a lot of information on  [W3schools](http://w3schools.com/)  ( among other sites ). I suggest focusing on HTML first, by playing with it on your home computer ( ie create a .html text file on your computer and open it on a browser ). And if you have problems along the way, this is a great site to post your questions on if all else fails.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding... I have the server and I'm (kind of) OK with the HTML side of it, PHP is a bit more complicated for me...

If I could start with how to get the data entered from the textbox into the script that you listed? I can create the HTML page wit hthe box, but I do not know how to make that interact with the JAVA example you gave. I think I actually understand the PHP part later and how it writes to the file. I am struggling with transferring the data from the form to the script and then onto the processing PHP page. Thanks!

Comment: I added some more explanation in the answer above. You should read a little up on javascript. while $.post isn't really 'advanced', you might need to understand the general syntax of the language before it completely makes sense.

Comment: Hi, I ended up going with this, which 'does' write to the file, but when the page is initially loaded it overwrites it by just loading the page. How can I stop it doing that and just writing on 'press submit'?

`code`<body>

<form name="form" method="post">

<input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php
if ($_REQUEST) {
    file_put_contents("filename.txt", $_REQUEST["text_box"]);
}
?>
 
</body>`code`

Comment: you'll have to put the php from your comment in a separate file, and call on that file with <form action="php_file.php" ...

Comment: also, the javascript in my answer is admittedly unnecessary compared to using the form tag - which apparently I've completely forgotten about